# How to mongoose list() - filtering values by subdocument field value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I'm implementing a paginated table that list some records that have subdocuments and i need to add filtering capabilities so that I can filter the list() results using the subdocument field values.

```
let HardwareSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }, // the exact name of the hardware.
    slug: { type: String, unique: true }, // the hardware's slug.
    category: { type: String, ref: 'HardwareCategory', required: true },
}

let HardwareCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true }, // the name of the category.
    slug: { type: String, unique: true }, // the slug of the category.
    description: { type: String, unique: true, required: true }, // the name of the category.
    createdBy: { type: String, ref: 'User', required: true } // the original submitter of the document.
});
```

So basically i want to to filter our Hardwares using category selected category.

Here is my the actual code;

```
const options = {
    perPage: 10,
    page: (req.query.page > 0 ? req.query.page : 1) - 1,
    sortBy: {'rank': -1 },
    criteria: {
        status: 'approved',
        category: {
             $elemMatch: { 'slug': category }
        }
    }
};

Hardware.list(options)
.then(results => {});
```

I'm getting the error; Can't use $elemMatch with String.

So basically i need to;

- be able to filter results based on subdocuments field value.
- be able to paginate results
- be able to sort results.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this option.

```
     const options = {
        perPage: 10,
        page: (req.query.page > 0 ? req.query.page : 1) - 1,
        sortBy: {'rank': -1 },
        criteria: {
          status: 'approved',
          'category.slug' : category 
        }
     };
```

or you can use find() like

```
      Hardware.find({
         'category.slug' : category 

     }, function(err, data){
     })
```